# Как правильно выгрузить тектовые данные в таблицу?

Tags: postgresql

Всем привет.
На данные момент изучаю PostgreSql(сам верстальщик).
И меня интересует такой вопрос:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как проще всего(и правильнее) выгружать подобные данные в новую таблицу?
(допустим если она еще не создана.)

1) Необходимо ли ее изначально создавать?
2) Необходимо ли прописывать заголовки предварительно?

Что только не пробовал писать - все время какие то синтаксические ошибки возникают..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен следующей командой:
COPY eurusd FROM 'D:\Progi 3\Trading\my-trading-app\static\EURUSD.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV;